# Assign port number manually for each connection

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming, system-calls

I'm running a server (say on port 50000). Any new request is accepted and a random port is assigned by OS each time. I want to manually assign the port number instead of system doing it randomly for me.

The main reason for this is I'm trying to do some multicast thing based on port number. I'm planning to assign few clients on same port. Next slot of clients on another port and so on.

Any idea?

Comment: You want multiple TCP connections on the same port? ...

Comment: The client gets a random (source) port when it opens the connection, but the port on the server stays the same. If you want clients to connect to different ports, you need to listen on multiple ports.

Comment: @deviantfan: Yes. Say, I want to connect n clients on 1 port only (say 55555) other than the port which is getting used for listen (say server is listening on 50000).

Comment: @deviantfan: Why? Any connection is a combination of 4 tuples: Client IP, Client Port, Server IP, Server Port. Here, every time my client IPs will be different.

Comment: why not open (aka listen to) different ports for each group of clients?

Comment: if you connect to `server:50000`, then you will always connect to port *50000* (so this is fixed). otoh, the *clients* will have "random" ports on their side; if you want these ports to be set manually, you need to fix them on the client-side

Comment: @umlaute: No, I don't want to open many ports in listen mode. It is like running n servers. In that case, clients will be dependent on these port numbers. I want a single port to listen. My question is, when I accept the connection, instead of OS giving a random port (on server side) to me, I want to set it explicitly. Any help on this?

Comment: Use bind() to assign a port to a socket.

Comment: You can insert a counter variable and increment it at each accept. When the variable reaches the value you want (which represents the number of clients on a given port), you can create a new socket and return it to the client with the new port to connect to.

Comment: "My question is, when I accept the connection, instead of OS giving a random port (on server side) to me, I want to set it explicitly." type man bind(2) on your terminal

Comment: @vjcalling: when you `accept()` a connection on the server side, the connection is assigned the client-side ip/port that made it and the server-side ip/port that accepted it. There is nothing random about that. You are getting your information mixed up.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: The server accepts it and assigns a random port. That is what is causing me trouble. I printed it on console and found, each time a new connection is accepted on a new port (from server side) and listen port remains same for future connections. Can I choose port number for these new connections on server side? Any help?

Comment: @vjcalling: NO, the server DOES NOT assign a *random* port to an accepted connection. It CANNOT assign a random port. Read my answer. The server assigns whatever *actual* ports are being used by the client and server ends of the connection. Only the client can choose a random port for itself before it connects to the server. It is normal and typical behavior for a client to use a random outbound port. To change that, you have to use `bind()` on the client side before calling `connect()`.

Answer (score 2):

A TCP socket is identified by a tuple of client-side IP/Port and server-side IP/Port pairs.  The server-side IP/Port is decided by calling `bind()` before `listen()`.  The client IP/Port is decided explicitly by calling `bind()` before `connect()`, or implicitly by omitting `bind()` and letting `connect()` decide.  When a connection is accepted by `accept()`, it is assigned the client-side IP/Port that made it and the server-side IP/Port that accepted it.

The only random option available here is on the client side.  It can call `connect()` without a preceding `bind()`, or it can call `bind()` with a zero IP/Port. In either case, the OS chooses an appropriate network adapter and assigns its IP if not explicitly stated, and assigns a random available ephemeral port if not explicitly stated.  Calling `bind()` allows the client to assign either/both of those values if desired.  `bind()` is not typically used on the client side in most situations, but it is allowed when needed when dealing with specific protocol requirements or firewall/router issues.

Tracking clients by Port alone is not good enough.  You need to track the full tuple instead, or at least the client-side IP/port pair of the tuple.  Clients from the same network would be using the same client IP but different Ports, but clients from different networks would be using different client IPs and could be using the same client Port, and that is perfectly OK.  So using Port alone may find the wrong client from the wrong network.  You need to take the client IP into account as well.

When the server accepts a connection, the server has no control over changing the values of the tuple. The OS needs the values to be predictable so it can route packets correctly.  When you want to send a packet to a specific client, you need to know both client IP and Port.

If you want to have different server-side IP/Port values in the tuples of accepted connections, the only option is to open multiple listening sockets that are bound with the desired server-side values.

Comment: +1 but 'the server has no control over changing the values of the tuple' and 'the OS needs the values to be predictable' because that's what it says in RFC 793: there is nothing in the TCP handshake that specifies a second port number.